# how to use constraint name in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tried creating table with constraint name in oracle and it succeed, when I tried in mysql, I get #1064 error.
this is my code :

```
create table penerbit( 
   id_penerbit char(3) constraint id_pk PRIMARY KEY,
   nama_penerbit varchar(100) constraint nama_nn NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: You cannot name `not null`-constraints in MySQL. The primary key name should work though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MySQL, you don't need to use the word "constraint".  So, the following should work in both Oracle and MySQL:

```
create table penerbit( 
    id_penerbit char(3) PRIMARY KEY,
    nama_penerbit varchar(100) NOT NULL
);
```

One note:  Oracle prefers `varchar2()` over `varchar()`.

If you want to name the constraints, you can add a separate declaration in both databases for the primary key:

```
create table penerbit ( 
    id_penerbit char(3),
    nama_penerbit varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    constraint id_pk primary key (id_penerbit)
);
```

Or you can do it in-line:

```
create table penerbit ( 
    id_penerbit char(3) constraint id_pk primary key,
    nama_penerbit varchar(100) NOT NULL
);
```

I don't think MySQL lets you name `NOT NULL` constraints, although Oracle does.